# Injections of subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the last step in the proof of this theorem:"To every $w$ in $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ corresponds a rational function $r$, with coefficients in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, such that $w = r(\xi_{j})$. Setting $\phi(w) = r(\phi(\xi_{j}))$ gives the desired injection." I don't understand why this final step is necessary, nor do I understand its purpose -- I thought that defining $\phi(\xi_j)$ was enough. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Theorem:
Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, $\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{m}$ are 
in $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathcal{F}_{1} = \mathcal{F}(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{m})$. Then either $\mathcal{F}_{1} = \mathcal{F}$, or there is an injection $\phi$ of $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ that fixes every element of $\mathcal{F}$ but moves at least one $\xi_{i}$.

PROOF:
Assume $\mathcal{F}_{1} \neq \mathcal{F}$. Then there is a nonempty subset of ${\xi_{1},\dots,\xi{m}}$, say $(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{j})$ (after reordering) that is minimal with respect to the property
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{F}_{1} = \mathcal{F}(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{j}).
\end{equation*}
Put $\mathcal{F}_{2} = \mathcal{F}(\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{j-1})$. (This is $\mathcal{F}$ when $j$ = 1.) Then
\begin{equation*}
 \mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_{2} \subsetneqq \mathcal{F}_{2}(\xi_{j}) = \mathcal{F}_{1}.
\end{equation*}

Let $\phi$ fix every element of $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ and choose $\phi(\xi_{j})$ as follows:
If $\xi_{j}$ is transcendental over $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, let $\phi(\xi_{j})$ be any complex number $\neq \xi_{j}$ that is also transcendental over $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ (such as 1 + $\xi_{j}$).
If $\xi_{j}$ is algebraic over $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, with minimal polynomial $p(x)$, let $\phi(\xi_{j})$ be another root of $p(x)$.
To every $w$ in $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ corresponds a rational function $r$, with coefficients in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, such that $w = r(\xi_{j})$. Setting $\phi(w) = r(\phi(\xi_{j}))$ gives the desired injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2(\xi_j)$, and the latter field by definition consists of rational functions in $\xi_j$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{F}_2$. Then the part you are having trouble understanding should be obvious. I think you were just unaware of what the notation $\mathcal{F}_2(\xi_j)$ meant.

Comment: thanks, this definitely clears things up partially, though I still don't understand why this final step is necessary? Isn't the injection already created?